# Etymology of Otho

Tags: etymology

Is there a currently accepted etymology for the name *Otho*? Lewis and Short suggest it comes from the Greek Ὄθων, which I suppose they mean comes from [ὄθομαι](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aalphabetic+letter%3D*o%3Aentry+group%3D6%3Aentry%3Do%29%2Fqomai), but how good is that suggestion? There's also [ὠθέω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dw)qe%2Fw), but from [Juvenal](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2007.01.0093%3Abook%3D1%3Apoem%3D2), the first O in Otho is definitely short.

For what it's worth, the OLD doesn't have an etymology for it.

Comment: FWIW, the [Lexicon of Greek Personal Names](http://www.lgpn.ox.ac.uk/database/lgpn.php) gives only one hit for Ὄθων (in volume 3A -- maybe this is the emperor). It certainly wasn't a common Greek name.

Comment: @TKR Good catch. There were a couple of Othones, so my bets are on this fellow being a Roman, not a Greek, though I don't have immediate access to the Lexicon.

Comment: Lewis and Short do not actually say that Latin Otho "comes from" the Greek Ὄθων, but rather that it "= Ὄθων", that is to say, that Ὄθων is the Greek spelling of this Roman name. It is a Latin cognomen.

Comment: The Wikipaedia article on Otho says that he came from an old Etruscan family, so perhaps the name is Etruscan in origin?  Hard to say, considering our lack of knowledge of Etruscan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Varro says in his comment above, the cognomen *Otho* might be Etruscan, because the family was apparently descended from Etruscan princes, according to Wikipaedia:

> Otho belonged to an ancient and noble Etruscan family, descended from the princes of Etruria and settled at Ferentinum (currently Ferento, near Viterbo) in Etruria.

Greek Ὄθων seems to have been a Graecification of the Roman cognomen.

There are of course many German *Othones (= Ottones)*, but it seems highly unlikely that an old, noble Roman family should adopt a Germanic name, if only because the Germans were still mostly far away in the east at the time.

*Utho* seems to have been an alternative spelling, as on the coin below. Etruscan names containing *-uth-* do exist. And according to Draconis below, Etruscan didn't distinguish between u and o, so this would fit into the theory of Etruscan origin.

[image]

Places like *Ut(h)ica* and *Uthina* exist in northern Africa, but it seems Utica was founded by (Semitic) Punics and hence unrelated to the Etruscan language. According to Wikipaedia, Uthina was a Berber town, but it would seem likely that its name, too, was originally Punic.

There are also the towns of *Othaea* and *Othoca* in western Sardinia. Pauly suggests an alternative spelling *Uta* for *Othaea* and says it is "wohl" ("arguably"?) Punic, like Utica.

Pauly doesn't say much at all about the origin of the name *Otho* itself:

[image]

I could not find the reference *Iunius Salvius Otho* at its expected place. There are over 200 Iunii with long articles in Pauly, ordered mostly alphabetically, but he wasn't there. Three Iunii Othones are mentioned, but nothing about their origin seems to have been known.

De Vaan remains silent.

Comment: The Otho/Utho ambiguity fits with an Etruscan origin, as the Etruscan language didn't distinguish those sounds.

Comment: @Draconis: Ah, I'm not surprised!

Comment: Thanks for the run-down. Without a definite etymology, I'm going to keep this open for a bit longer, though, hoping someone will know something further.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer: Naturally! It's not exactly an answer.

Comment: Well, sometimes "we don't know" is an acceptable answer!

Comment: @C.M.Weimer: Fair enough!